# UIViewController's view strange resizing behavior

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've created a `UIViewController` with a `UIView` defined in the `loadView` method. When I presented the `UIViewController`'s view size in the `viewDidAppear:` method changed to an enormous size. I will describe the solution in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I've created an iPhone project. Then changed it to iPhone/iPad project. And in the `MainWindow.xib` file the iPhone settings remained. Because of this, the system increased my view's size to a big number. The solution was to create another XIB file named `MainWindow~ipad.xib` and set the window size properly.

If anybody has any question about this problem, please don't hesitate to ask it.